# Keep textbox in sync with richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wrote a program in VB.net that has multiple textboxes with values (read from an INI file).
And I have added a richtextbox with the complete INI file so people can edit it directy without the using the textboxes.

Is it possible to update the richtextbox with the values added to the textboxes?
And is it possible to update the textboxes with the values from the richtextbox?

This is the code I use to show the value of the INI file:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenINI.Click
    wEditor.LoadFile(File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get all the individual entries from the RichTextBox into your TextBoxes?...

Comment: Please illustrate what you are trying to do with some screenshots. Otherwise not quite clear.

Comment: Ok...so right now you have nothing that is parsing the RichTextBox to get the values into the corresponding controls.  I recommend you take a look at the [GetPrivateProfileString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx) API as it can give you all of the sections and their values.  There are lots of examples on the internet.  Parsing the RichTextBox in real-time as it is changed is more difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

Idle_Mind; I use:

```
    Private Sub OpenINIButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenINIButton.Click

    Dim OpenDLG As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenDLG.Filter = Configuration File (*.ini)|*.ini"
    OpenDLG.Title = "Open INI File"
    OpenDLG.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenDLG.RestoreDirectory = True

    DialogResult = OpenDLG.ShowDialog

    If DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        File = OpenDLG.FileName.ToString()
        **wEditor.LoadFile(File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)**
    ElseIf DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then

    End If

End Sub
```

to get the data in the richtextbox.

Neolist; Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want the data from the textboxes and the RichTextBox to be in sync.